# How can I read the value of a toggle btn?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I know what the button is pressed with javaScript?

```html
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
  <div id="insert_data__radio_gender" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_f" autocomplete="off">Female
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_m" autocomplete="off">Male
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what property you want to read ? and only by javascript or you can use jquary as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is live example using JQuery:

```js
$('.btn-group input').on('change', function() {
  alert($('input[name="options"]:checked', '.btn-group').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
  <div id="insert_data__radio_gender" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_f" autocomplete="off" value="Female">Female
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_m" autocomplete="off" value="Male">Male
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JQuery you can use this:

```
$('input[name="options"]:checked').val();
```

You need to add the value attribute to the buttons tho.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could add a value="f" and value="m" or get data from id's

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
  <div id="insert_data__radio_gender" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_f" value="f" autocomplete="off">Female
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_m" value="m" autocomplete="off">Male
   </label>
 </div>
</div>
<button onclick="chkRadios();">Check</button>
```

**JS**

```
function chkRadios(){
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('options');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
          alert(radios[i].id);
          alert(radios[i].value);
          break;
      }
  }
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tj8q8ndb/)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is give both of your radio buttons values:

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
    <div id="insert_data__radio_gender" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" value="female" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_f" autocomplete="off">Female
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" value="male" name="options" id="insert_data__radio_gender_m" autocomplete="off">Male
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('input[name='options']:checked').val();
```

Or in plain javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('options');
var gender;
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
        gender = inputs[i].value;
    }
}
```

Or for IE9+ (plain javascript):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested) code and please, let me know if it works:

```
var semaphores = {};
var myCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("label.btn-primary");
for (var checkbox in myCheckboxes) {
    var myCheckbox = myCheckboxes[checkbox].querySelector("input");
    semaphores[checkbox] = true;
    myCheckboxes[checkbox].onclick = function() {
        if (!semaphores[checkbox]) {
            semaphores[checkbox] = true;
            return;
        }
        semaphores[checkbox] = false;
        myCheckbox.click();
        return false;
    };
    myCheckbox.onclick = function() {
        semaphores[checkbox] = false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var idOfSelected = $('input[type=radio][name=options]:checked').attr('id');
    if(idOfSelected=="insert_data__radio_gender_f")
       alert("Female");
    else
       alert("Male");
```

If you don't want to set value attribute you can also do this

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#insert_data__radio_gender").on("change",function(){
  var female=($("#insert_data__radio_gender_f").is("checked"));
  var male=($("#insert_data__radio_gender_m").is("checked"));
});
```

You can use `$("#selector_id").is("checked")` to check whether the input is  checked or not